# How to tell if a user has voted on a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reddit

I'm creating a Rails app for use with [Reddit's API](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api).

How can I go about telling if a logged in user has voted on a link before? And which direction did they vote?

Comment: Check out http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_user_{username}_{where}, and perhaps the POST Vote method in the API.

Comment: @David I'm not seeing that GET_user_ section.

Comment: It's under Users (2nd from the bottom on the table of contents bar)

Comment: Let me know if it gives you desired results. :)

Comment: @David I actually found another solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if a user is logged in, in the `JSON` of a listing item there is a variable `likes`

`likes` is `true` for an upvote, `false` for a downvote and `null` for no vote.